# Is there a monochrome version of the SO logo available somewhere?

Tags: support, logo

I want to use it on my webpage to link to my SO account. Even a color version will work. Thanks!

Comment: I found [this](https://sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/about/logo-so.svg). You probably also ought to read [the trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: Oh so I can’t use the logo?

Comment: I’m not sure whether you can or cannot use the logo—I’m not a lawyer. I do know that the logo is covered by a trademark, and that they have published guidelines that I linked to.

Comment: @icktoofay the logo is copyrighted (way at the bottom of the website) :(

Comment: "*Do feel free to use names or logos for the purpose of labeling our sites within your product, as long as use of such logos could not be confused with the branding or endorsement of the product itself.*"

Comment: @TinyGiant Yaay.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily go and use it based on that, I'm not a lawyer but I would say that you have to take care how you use it. You cannot make it appear as if stackoverflow endorses your website and you cannot make it appear that you created the image. I'm not sure what that means exactly, but I do think it deserves a better explanation

Comment: Find the logo's [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos) and read [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo)

Comment: Any image editor will allow you to convert an image from color to grayscale.

Answer (score 4):

[Font Awesome has a Stack Overflow logo.](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/stack-overflow/)  IANAL, but be sure that you're using it in accordance with the [guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).